# Is there an optimal intergalactical travelling speed?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, speed

In our perceiveable world, an increment of speed typically results in needing less time to travel a given distance. When I go by car, it takes less time then going by bike. However, there is the timeparadoxon. It means, if someone could travel with a speed all close light speed, he would go to his destination and back very fast, but the people waiting for him will turn lots of older during this time anyhow. That is, it still takes long for them. So, from a perspective of the remainers, shouldn’t there be an “optimal” speed for the travelling so that the travelyan, for the remainers, comes back the most early possible? I mean, in my imagination, this should form a U-shaped graph: First, the faster the travelyan goes, the time gets less, then at some point the effects of timeparadoxon kick in and the time to return increases again. From this formula, it should be possible to find a minimum.

Is there such a thing and, does it depend on the distance or is it a constant? If there was such a constant, this would mean very sure observing objects in the space that move at this speed would be highly probably be a space ship! This is why I interest in it.

Comment: It may be useful to note that the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ is a monotonic function of $v$.

Answer (score 2):

From the perspective of a stationary observer, time dilation has absolutely nothing to do with when they see the traveler return, since they themselves do not experience any time dilation. They simply see someone travelling some distance *L* and back, so the greater their speed, the sooner they return. The traveler will have a different perception of time as they approach *c*, so they will disagree with the stationary person's elapsed time, but that does not change how long the stationary person waited in their reference frame.

The traveler's speed does not affect the stationary observer's  perception of time in any way. All they can do to come home faster is to cover the distance as quickly as possible - it doesn't matter if they're just heading down the road to the chemist's or to the end of the universe, going faster gets them there... faster.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no optimal speed. When traveling a distance $L$ and the coming back, the time required is $\dfrac{2L}{v}$ according to the person on earth and $2L/v\gamma$ for the traveler. Both of these are strictly decreasing functions of $v$.